# "WebSocket connection to ... failed" on AWS, but works locally

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, amazon-elb

When running my application locally, my Websocket connection opens successfully with the 101 response. However, when in production, on AWS, the websocket cannot connect.

> WebSocket connection to
> 'wss://www.tidee.com:3002/socket.io/?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIwZGI4ZDgyMWUzYWM0MTYyM2E0OWIzY2IwZTA5OGJiMiIsImlhdCI6MTYyNTQwMzU2OSwiZXhwIjoxNjI1NDg5OTY5fQ.SFNbOLouyM-t2dM9LufQzNj4cwj_ApxhN6lQv7Objac&EIO=3&transport=websocket'
> failed:

I have HTTPS 443 and 3002 listeners set up on the load balancer. Is there something obvious I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You may not have whitelisted port 3002 in security group.

1. Load balancer security group and Instance (ec2, ecs,...) security group for Application Load Balancer
2. Instance (ec2, ecs,...) security group for Network Load Balancer.

Refer below image for sample security group entries.

[image]

Please whitelist IPs as required.

Comment: I have added 3002, a per your image, to the Load Balancer and Instance security groups that the Elastic Beanstalk states in the configuration, but I am still getting the same error.